# Why does PostgreSQL sorts on a boolean WHERE condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan, explain, query-planner

I am testing some queries over a bunch of materialized views. All of them have the same structure, like this one:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT mr.foo, ..., CAST(SUM(mr.bar) AS INTEGER) AS stuff
    FROM foo.bar mr
    WHERE
        mr.a = 'TRUE' AND
        mr.b = 'something' AND
        mr.c = '12'
    GROUP BY
        mr.a,
        mr.b,
        mr.c;
```

Obviously the system is giving me a different query plan for each one of them, but if (and only if) a WHERE clause involves a boolean column (like in the examples), the planner **always** sorts the result set before finishing. Example:

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=16305.92..16317.98 rows=85 width=21) (actual time=108.301..108.301 rows=1 loops=1)
   Group Key: festivo, nome_strada, ora
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=16305.92..16315.05 rows=70 width=77) (actual time=108.279..109.015 rows=2 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=15305.90..15306.95 rows=35 width=77) (actual time=101.422..101.422 rows=1 loops=3)
               Group Key: festivo, nome_strada, ora
               ->  Sort  (cost=15305.90..15305.99 rows=35 width=21) (actual time=101.390..101.395 rows=28 loops=3)
                     Sort Key: festivo
                     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on sft_vmv3_g3 mr  (cost=0.00..15305.00 rows=35 width=21) (actual time=75.307..101.329 rows=28 loops=3)
                           Filter: (festivo AND ((nome_strada)::text = '16th St'::text) AND (ora = '12'::smallint))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 277892
```

I am really curios about this kind of approach, but I still haven't found an explaination about this.

Comment: It probably thinks the sort is cheaper than a HashAggregate. What is your setting for `work_mem`?  (btw: you should either use the boolean column as a boolean, e.g. `where mr.a` or provide a proper boolean literal not a string, e.g. `where mr.a =  true`)

Comment: `work_mem` is 4MB. About the literal, according to [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-boolean.html) it shouldn't matter.

Comment: You can try to increase work_mem (e.g. to 64MB) and see if that changes the plan to a HashAggregate

Comment: If `a` is a BOOLEAN, why are you comparing it to a string constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious why you wouldn't phrase the logic as:

```
SELECT true as a, 'something' as b, '12' as c, CAST(SUM(mr.bar) as INTEGER)
FROM foo.bar as mr
WHERE mr.a AND
      mr.b = 'something' AND
      mr.c = '12';
```

This an aggregation query (because of the `SUM()` in the `SELECT`) and does not have an explicit `GROUP BY`.  I think it should produce a more optimal execution plan.  In addition, it will always return one row, even if no rows match the condition.

Comment: Should the `WHERE ` condition start with `WHERE mr.a = 'TRUE' AND...`? `mr.a` appears to be a VARCHAR or something of that nature, rather than a BOOLEAN.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . This is an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`.  All such queries return exactly one row.

Comment: @BobJarvis . . . The text of the question mentions a boolean column in the `WHERE`.  The only reasonable candidate is `a`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e19d94236d5ed64ffd5d3b214cb1c9c1.